# How do I sort (order) the results from `get_children()`?

Tags: posts, theme-development, images

I have a post that contain images, let's say image with id 19, 12, 10.
I attach image 19 first, 12 below the first and 10 as the last, and I need to retrieve them. I

```
$post_images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $id,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
));
```

But i receive them sorted by id (10,12,19), how i get them with the order as i needed

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation for `get_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) isn't great (at the time of this answer), however `get_children` is simply a wrapper for [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). This means that `orderby` and `order` are valid arguments for your query.

When you ask, "*how i get them with the order as i needed*", is the property you wish to order them by a [valid `orderby` value](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)? If so, your function call might look like this:

```
$post_images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $id,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'title'
    'order' => 'ASC',
));
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understood, you want to get the attachment by the same order that you uploaded them. You can sort them by date, in this case:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'post_type'        => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'   => 'image',
    'post_parent'      => $id,
    'post_status'      => 'inherit',
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

This will sort your attachments by their date, which would most likely be what you are looking for.